# Integration of google sign in to my website

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am trying to integrate google sign in to my website.Its working, but i want to remove the text 'sign in' beside google icon. what attribute has to be added to the following predefined class by google?

```
<span class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"  >
```

[image: This is my screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify settings for a custom Google Sign-In button by defining `data-` attributes to a `div` element with the class `g-signin2`. See [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) for examples

Comment: Thank you Tony Vincent.I used 'data-width' attribute and its working

Comment: @HareeshKumarK glad it helped

Comment: But 'data-width' option is not helpful to remove "login" text from facebook icon. can you please help me what to do 

This is my code for fb icon

                                            
 <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" data-size="large" data-width="10" onlogin="checkLoginState();">